# Horizontal Pocket button

Tags: html, css

Has anyone been able to get the `Pocket` button to work horizontally.

I am using the documentation described here
https://getpocket.com/publisher/button

The problem is this button always comes in its own line and does line it with others. See here:
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/05/07/portablejekyllupdated.html

Is there a way I can line it along with other buttons horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

**CSS**

```
.pocket-btn {
  display: inline-block
}
```

to the **HTML**

```
<a data-pocket-label="pocket" data-pocket-count="horizontal" class="pocket-btn" data-lang="en"></a>
<span>asdf</span>

<script type="text/javascript">!function(d,i){if(!d.getElementById(i)){var j=d.createElement("script");j.id=i;j.src="https://widgets.getpocket.com/v1/j/btn.js?v=1";var w=d.getElementById(i);d.body.appendChild(j);}}(document,"pocket-btn-js");</script>
```

**RESULT**

[image: RESULT]

[SEE CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/fEhLc)